# Trouble with passing a value into loop

Tags: java, arrays, io

The code below runs perfectly fine if the text file consists of lines of numbers but once it gets to for example a line that says "I am 40" it skips it instead of putting 40 into the array.

```
Scanner inFile = null;
    File file = null;
    String filePath = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a file path"));
    int size = 0;
    int[] result = new int[10];


    try {
        file = new File(filePath);
        inFile = new Scanner(file);
        int skippedCounter = 0;

        for(int i = 0; inFile.hasNext(); i++){
            if(inFile.hasNextInt())
                result[i] = inFile.nextInt();
            else{
                String strOut = "";
                String data = inFile.next();

                for(int j = 0; j <= data.length() - 1; j++){
                    if(!Character.isLetter(data.charAt(j))){
                        strOut += data.charAt(j);
                    }
                    else
                        skippedCounter++;
                }
                result[i] = Integer.parseInt(strOut);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`next()` will give you the next token not the next Line. so variable `i` may go past ten. you would realize this if you didnt have an empty catch : that your array is going out of bounds

solution:

don't use a result array, use a result list, and append to its end whenever you have another result

note:

another hidden exception that could be occurring is when your parseInt fails due to non-numeric data. So don't wrap everything in a giant try/catch, it just makes it harder to debug!

Comment: That worked but now I have an issue where when I print my arraylist to array, there are empty elements i cant seem to get rid of

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use nextInt function just one time to keep the requested value, then use that variable whenever you need it. I think nextInt function moves to the next int each time you appeal it.

Answer (score 0):

The following

```
result[i] = Integer.parseInt(strOut)
```

will result in a `NumberFormatException` when trying to process any letter. As `strOut` results in an empty String `""`

You'll have to check for an empty String before attempting to parse

```
if (!strOut.isEmpty()) {
    result[i] = Integer.parseInt(strOut);
}
```